# BeanUtils to call the size() method of a collection (which is not a setter)

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a class with a getter and setter:

```
class A
{
  private Set<Offers> offers;

  public Set<Offers> getOffers(){
    return offers;
  }

  public void setOffers(Set<Offers> offers){
    this.offers = offers;
  }

}
```

Now I wanted to get the size() of the offers using Apache Commons PropertyUtils:

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(myAInstance, "offers.size");
```

This should basically do the same as:

```
myAInstance.getOffers().size();
```

But using the PropertyUtils doesn't work and gives me a:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'size' on class
>   'class java.util.LinkedHashSet'

Using PropertyUtils to all getters and setters on other objects is working fine.

I suspect it is because the size() method of a Collection is not following the getXXX and setXXX bean convention.

Is there another way to use PropertyUtils / or BeanUtils (or anything else from Apache Commons) to call the size() method of my collection?

Thanks
Christoph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PropertyUtils is named "PropertyUtils" for a reason.  It works on the java beans conventions.  The "size()" method does not conform to that convention, so you can't refer to it as a property.

Perhaps you're better of with a something like MVEL or GroovyScript which supports both property navigation and function invocation.  Here's a sample for mvel which should work

```
Integer size = (Integer) MVEL.eval("offers.size()", instanceOfA);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I know MVEL is not apache commons, but it's using the Apache 2.0 license, which is exactly what all the commons packages should be using I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that an expression language is more what I was looking for, and I expected the wrong thing of PropertyUtils. I will give MVEL a try.

Answer (score 1):

A way around it (couldn't get it to work) + I concur with Dave 'Not entirely clear why you'd want to'

add this to your A class

```
public int getOfferSize(){
    return offers == null ? 0 : offers.size();
}
```

Then use

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(myAInstance, "offerSize");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear why you'd want to, although it does offer some thin wrappers around the reflection API.

You'll want to use the [`MethodUtils` class](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html), specifically one of the [`invokeExactMethod`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#invokeExactMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) or [`invokeMethod` variants](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Hmm seems MethodUtils and the invokeMethod variants do not support nested definitions of the method. I would like to be able to say invokeMethod("offers.size") and I would like it to call two methods getOffers().getSize(), both methods without any arguments. But this also gives me a: No such accessible method: offers.size() on object

Comment: @Christoph It's not an expression language, and except for OGNL (now an Apache project) and the JSP EL stuff, I'm not aware of anything in Commons that is. Is it really that difficult to combine bean utils and property utils in a trivial utility method? Or perhaps you should take another approach, like scripting.

Comment: Ok thanks Dave. The "expression language" way to look at it makes sense. Hmm ok, I think at first I will go with the workaround by D3mon-1stVFW and also try out MVEL mentioned by Matt. I think MVEL is more what I was looking for. Regarding the combination of Property/BeanUtils: it is not too difficult (and I already hacked it...) but thought that this functionality is already provided but maybe I was to blind to find it... :) Thanks

Comment: @Christoph MVEL is also faster than OGNL, and has similar expressivity. You can do some... "interesting" things with either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through good old reflection directly, avoiding any libraries.

First, you get the getter:

```
Method get = A.class.getDeclaredMethod("getOffers");
```

Now you invoke the getter and obtain the object that represents the set. Then you create a new Method representing the size method defined in Set:

```
Object setFromA= get.invoke(yourAObject);
Method size = Set.class.getDeclaredMethod("size");
```

Finally, you cast the method on setFromA and get the size, casting your setFromA object to the required type:

```
Integer listSize = (Integer) size.invoke(get.getReturnType().cast(setFromA));
```

Comment: yes that's how I hacked it for now, but I liked the nested property syntax of PropertyUtils as 90% of the stuff are getters/setters. I will either stick to getters/setters or try an expression language like MVEL.